# JSON Object to Array of String

Tags: android, arrays, json, string, e-commerce

We are developing an Ecommerce Mobile Application but here we are facing an problem in passing an array of string to an Json Object. Whenever we are passing the same it is throwing an error as attached in the Log. It seems like an extra "\" is coming up.

Please find below my code Snippet:

try {

```
            stFullName=Edit_FullName.getText().toString();

            Log.e("BillingName",stFullName);

            stEmailId=Edit_EmaiAdress.getText().toString();

            stAddress=Edit_Adress.getText().toString();

            stCity=Edit_City.getText().toString();

            stState=Edit_State.getText().toString();

            stZipCode=Edit_ZipCode.getText().toString();

            stPhoneNo=Edit_MobileNumber.getText().toString();

            stCountry=Edit_Country.getText().toString();

            stLandmark=Edit_Landmark.getText().toString();

            jsonObject1.put("BillingName",stFullName);

            jsonObject1.put("BillingEmail",stEmailId);

            jsonObject1.put("BillingTelephone",stPhoneNo);

            jsonObject1.put("BillingCountry",stCountry);

            jsonObject1.put("BillingZip",stZipCode);

            jsonObject1.put("BillingCity",stCity);

            jsonObject1.put("BillingState",stState);

            jsonObject1.put("BillingLandmark",stLandmark);

            jsonObject1.put("GrandTotal",ProductAmount);
          jsonObject1.put("BillingAddress",stAddress).toString().replaceAll("\\\\","");

            jsonObject1.put("DeviceID",deviceId);

            jsonObject1.put("IsDifferentShipping",false);

            String jsonFormattedString = jSonData;

            Log.e("jsonFormattedString",jsonObject1.toString());

            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();

            jsonArray.put(productArray);

            Log.e("productArray",productArray.toString());

            productArray = productArray.toString().replaceAll("\\\\","").trim();

            jsonObject1.put("ChekoutProductsModel_List",productArray.toString().replaceAll("\\\\",""));
            Log.e("productArray", jsonObject1.toString().replaceAll("\\\\","").trim());
```

//

```
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.e("object1",jsonObject1.toString()); 


            JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, Config.Url.concat(getMakePayment),
                    jsonObject1, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject Response) {
                    Log.e("jsonResponse",Response.toString());
                    try {
                        String jsonResponse=Response.getString("ResponseObject");
                        Log.e("ResponseBilling",jsonResponse);
                        if(jsonResponse.equals("Billing info save successfully!")){
                            Toast.makeText(context,jsonResponse,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Intent intent=new Intent(context,ProductReview.class);
                            intent.putExtra("product_id",ProductCode);
                            intent.putExtra("stock_id",StockId);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                        else {
                            Toast.makeText(context,jsonResponse,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
```

If any body can please check and help us out on the same.

Comment: Error StackTrace ?

Comment: Where's the log you mentioned?